# CMBR: Is the cold spot a hint at the edge of the universe?

Tags: universe, cosmic-microwave-background

Could the big [cold spot in the CMBR map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMB_cold_spot) be a sign that almost all radiation from that direction has already passed us, and that be a sign that the end of the universe is closest to earth in that direction?

Comment: Can you provide a reference? Where did you hear about the cold spot?

Comment: I have to say I'm not into physics but fascinated by cosmological hypotheses. Nevertheless the cold spot seems to be part of well established astrophysics, see for instance https://www.telegiz.com/articles/23750/20170519/scientists-reveal-first-evidence-multiverse-indeed-exists.htm

Comment: @Jim421616 I've added a link to the Cold Spot's Wikipedia page

Comment: There isn't an end/edge of the universe in the sense you mean it.

Comment: I'm not sure myself how I mean it. But there are countless articles in the WWW talking about the size, radius, and similar, of the universe. So there should also be some kind of end to it, as long as one does not assume an infinite universe, or one that has a geometry that leads to a "pacman"-effect. The professor in the article I linked above claims that the cold spot is an imprint of a neighbouring universe, which also implies that our universe ends at some point.

Comment: Even the professionals are divided on the question whether there is some end or edge to the universe and how to define it. https://www.quora.com/Does-the-universe-have-an-edge?share=1 is a thread on that topic.